# Add Vue Sfc to existing project

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue3-sfc-loader

i have a legacy project and wanted to start using Vue.js single file components using the CDN. I did bump into some plugins such as https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader.
Is there any solution from CDN point of view that we can:

- generic mount to the root of the page / body ?
- add every *.vue file from /components folder?

Then we could call those components anywhere in the existing page.
I believe the plugin https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader only allows us to mount to a specific div#app and add a custom template (at least following the examples provided)
Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending lots of time in this investigation, I went for the [Vue Web Components approach](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html)

Adding all the components to a /components folder, we will just need to have a package.json like the following

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service build --target wc '/components/*.vue' --name my-app",
    "watch": "node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service build --watch --target wc '/components/*.vue' --name my-app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.12",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
```

And add the following vue.config.js file in order to
have only one file in the bundle

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // No need for splitting
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    }
  }
}
```

Then by adding

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="./dist/my-app.min.js"></script>
```

to the page, we are able to use the components (see dist/demo.html to confirm the final name of the components)
And for me this delivered what was needed. Hope someone can find it useful.